# ROS - How do I publish a message and get the subscribed callback immediately

Tags: ros

I have a ROS node that allows you to "publish" a data structure to it, to which it responds by publishing an output. The timestamp of what I published and what it publishes is matched.

Is there a mechanism for a blocking function where I send/publish and output, and it waits until I receive an output?

Comment: If you are looking for fast communication, ROS communication is not your purpose because it is slower than a broker-less communicator like ZeroMQ. ROS-service pattern equivalent in [ZeroMQ is REQ/REP](https://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyzmq/patterns/client_server.html).

Comment: Yes I have decided to ditch ROS as its too slow for my needs. I'm surprised it cant even handle a 512x512 organized point cloud at 60 fps within localhost

Comment: I updated my answer in the UPDATE section, hope help you up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need the ROS_Services (client/server) pattern instead of the publisher/subscriber.

---

Here is a simple example to do that in Python:

Client code snippet:

```py
import rospy
from test_service.srv import MySrvFile

rospy.wait_for_service('a_topic')
try:
    send_hi = rospy.ServiceProxy('a_topic', MySrvFile)
    print('Client: Hi, do you hear me?')
    resp = send_hi('Hi, do you hear me?')
    print("Server: {}".format(resp.response))

except rospy.ServiceException, e:
    print("Service call failed: %s"%e)
```

---

Server code snippet:

```py
import rospy
from test_service.srv import MySrvFile, MySrvFileResponse

def callback_function(req):
    print(req)
    return MySrvFileResponse('Hello client, your message received.')

rospy.init_node('server')
rospy.Service('a_topic', MySrvFile, callback_function)
rospy.spin()
```

---

MySrvFile.srv

```
string request
---
string response
```

---

Server out:

```
request: "Hi, do you hear me?"
```

Client out:

```
Client: Hi, do you hear me?
Server: Hello client, your message received.
```

---

> [Learn more in ros-wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28python%29)

- Project repo on [GitHub](https://github.com/agn-7/test_service).

---

[UPDATE]

- If you are looking for fast communication, TCP-ROS communication is not your purpose because it is slower than a broker-less communicator like ZeroMQ (it has low latency and high throughput):

1. ROS-Service pattern equivalent in ZeroMQ is [REQ/REP (client/server)](https://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyzmq/patterns/client_server.html)
2. ROS publisher/subscriber pattern equivalent in ZeroMQ is [PUB/SUB](https://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyzmq/patterns/pubsub.html)
3. ROS publisher/subscriber with `waitformessage` equivalent in ZeroMQ is [PUSH/PULL](https://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyzmq/patterns/pushpull.html)

> ZeroMQ is available in both Python and C++

- Also, to transfer huge amounts of data (e.g. `pointcloud`), there is a mechanism in ROS called [`nodelet`](http://wiki.ros.org/nodelet) which is supported only in C++. This communication is based on shared memory on a machine instead of TCP-ROS socket.

  > [What exactly is a nodelet?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/19409/18870)

Comment: Hey I saw we answered the question at the same time. I think your answer is more detailed, should I delete my answer then?

Comment: Hi @Malefitz, No needs to delete, since that our answers have different content (you mentioned a C++ example ... )

Comment: yes i guess my only choice is to change my entire codebase to nodelet format, which will require a month of engineering time.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to stick with publish/ subscribers, assuming from your comment, that services are to slow I would have a look at `waitForMessage` ([Documentation](http://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/roscpp/html/namespaceros_1_1topic.html#a36c2ef749111e9a7eed7d08d0dfdfba4)).

And for an example on how to use it you can have a look at [this ros answers question](https://answers.ros.org/question/293890/how-to-use-waitformessage-properly/).

All you need to do is to publish your data and immediately call waitForMessage on the output topic and manually pass the received message to your "callback".

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: waitForMessage is too slow. Looks like there is no way around this and ROS doesnt have a fast version of such a mechanism.

Comment: So the question is, do you want to have different nodes/processes for request/reply or can it be the same (or a nodelet). If different processes of course it's going to be slow because you include the TCP/IP overhead in the communication. But at least for publish/subscribe there is the possibility to use shared pointers for the message and if the same process then publishes and subscribes the message gets passed via shared memory which is much faster. Needs to be found out if this also works for services.

Answer (score 0):

To get this request/reply behaviour ROS has a mechanism called [ROS service](http://wiki.ros.org/Services).

You can specify the input and output of your service in a service file similar to a ROS message definition. You can then call the service of a node with your input and the call will receive an output when the service is finished.

[Here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient(python)) is a tutorial how to use this mechanism in python. If you prefer C++ there is also one, you should find it.

Comment: rosservice is too slow. it takes 50 ms just to make a call