# ROS: Is ZeroMQ better for large data streams, e.g. raw images, than native image topic?

Tags: python, zeromq, ros

Fairly new to ROS, but haven't been able to find this information searching around.

We're building an instrument where we need to transfer large data streams over the network on a 100Mbit limited cable. Preferably we need to transfer RAW images (~10MB a piece) or we can do some lossless compression resulting in about 5MB a piece.

Is this perfectly fine for ROS with native image topics, or would a separate protocol such as ZeroMQ be better for this task? What are the limitations in ROS on large data streams?

Hope that someone with the knowledge could take a second to share some experience.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are looking for fast communication, ROS communication is not your purpose because it is slower than a broker-less communicator like ZeroMQ. Or you could use [`nodelet`](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/19399/what-exactly-is-a-nodelet/19409#19409) instead of ROS-TCP (topic based) in ROS. [Also check the UPDATE section of this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58638958/3702377)

Comment: Your welcome, if these posts helped you up, please consider plus for them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`10E6 [B] over a private, 100% free 100E6 [b/s] channel takes` **`no less ~0.8 [s]`**
`_5E6 [B] over a private, 100% free 100E6 [b/s] channel takes` **`no less ~0.4 [s]`**

> **Q** : *What are the limitations in `<something>` on large data streams?*

Here we always fight a three-fold Devil mix of:

**Power**( for data processing, a ***`10[MB]->5[MB]`*** compression + RAM-I/O not being excluded )
+
**Time**( latency + jitter of the E2E data-transport across the series of transport-channels )
+
**Errors**( uncertainties of content delivery, completeness and authenticity over the E2E data-transport path )

In the ROS domain, being a system for coordinated control-loops' constrained sub-systems, there is one more problem - not meeting the "in-time-ness" causes the control to fail into principally unstable territory.

> Countless examples of what happens when this border has been crossed - from production line falling into panic, resulting in an immediate emergency total-stop state, to damaged tools, products, equipment and continued colliding, still crashing during still continued operations ( when collision-detection and emergency total-stops were not implemented safe ).

---

> **Q** : *would a separate protocol such as ZeroMQ be better for this task?*

ZeroMQ has excellent **performance** ( does not add much on the **Time** leg of the Devil-mix, yet it always depends on having (in-)sufficient resources ( the **Power** to smoothly process )

ZeroMQ has excellent **performance scalability,** sure, if the **Power** leg of the Devil-mix permits.

ZeroMQ has excellent properties for the **Errors** leg of the Devil-mix - we get warranty of Zero-Errors - it either delivers the message (the payload) as a bit-to-bit identical copy of the original content, or nothing at all. This warranty may look strange, a sure overkill for blurred or noisy images - yet, it is a fair strategy for not having additional **Power** and **Time**-uncertainty issues due to error-detection/limited-recovery. Yet it leaves us free with choices, how to handle (if needed), within a given, constrained, **Time**- and **Power**-domains, the main duty - the ROS control-loops' stability - with missing or re-transmit requested payloads, given **Errors** were indirectly detected from time-stamping or monotonic-ordinal indexing et al.

ROS `Topics`, on the contrary, are limited to a single `PUB/SUB` formal communication-pattern archetype only and fixed to use either a `TCPROS` transport-class ( ZeroMQ may use a faster, L3+protocol stack-less **`{ inproc:// | ipc:// }`** or, if needed, even extended to a mil-std guaranteed-delivery or a distributed grid-computing `tipc://` or hypervisor-orchestrated `vmci://` transports ) or `UDPROS`, which is currently available in `roscpp` only and lossy, but having lower latency, compared to `TCPROS`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer on these topics! From what I interpret from your answer (and experience - I guess) is that you indeed recommend  ZeroMQ over ROS Topics for our specific application, yes?

Comment: In most cases, the ROS / Topics may operate for ROS-native modules and the 10GB-sized image acquisition (+ pre-processing, if opted-in ) and processing will best reside within the stability constrained timing - be it with or without ZeroMQ. Without your actual context of use, there is not a single one, best, approach. I would prefer to have rather any 10GB-acquisition immediately processed on the same node, perhaps with added, dedicated CPU-power, rather than trying to solve a quadrature of a circle, where moving 10GB over any private, the less shared 0.1Gbps Ethernet hops to remote process'em